# Generic Poly2 Folder case for shapeless Hlist

Tags: scala, generics, fold, shapeless, hlist

I am trying to transform the following HList

```
Some(C(15)) :: None :: Some(B(55)) :: None :: Some(A(195)) :: HNil
```

to

```
C(15) :: B(55) :: A(195) :: HNil
```

Here is what I have at the moment :

```
  import shapeless._
  case class A(value: Int)
  case class B(value: Int)
  case class C(value: Int)

  trait folderLP extends Poly2 {
    implicit def default[T, L <: HList] = at[T, L]((acc, t) => acc)
  }
  object folder extends folderLP {
    implicit def none[T, L <: HList] = at[None.type, L]((t, acc) => acc)

    implicit def someDiameter[T, L <: HList] = at[Some[C], L]((t, acc) => t.get :: acc)

    implicit def someRatio[T, L <: HList] = at[Some[B], L]((t, acc) => t.get :: acc)

    implicit def someWidth[T, L <: HList] = at[Some[A], L]((t, acc) => t.get :: acc)
  }
  val test = Some(C(15)) :: None :: Some(B(55)) :: None :: Some(A(195)) :: HNil

  val filtered = test.foldRight[HList](HNil)(folder)
```

this works but I would like to make this generic so that it works for any type wrapped in Some without having to write each case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First for a literal answer. Note that most of your `T` type parameters aren't being used. You can use that `T` to make your function match any element of type `Some[T]`:

```
trait folderLP extends Poly2 {
  implicit def default[T, L <: HList] = at[T, L]((_, acc) => acc)
}

object folder extends folderLP {
  implicit def some[T, L <: HList] = at[Some[T], L]((t, acc) => t.get :: acc)
}
```

Note that you don't even need the `none` case if you switch the order of arguments in your `default`.

Also note that you probably want to use the following definition of `filtered`:

```
val filtered = test.foldRight(HNil: HNil)(folder)
```

This one will have the `HNil` statically typed as an `HNil` instead of an `HList`, which will be useful for pretty much anything you want to do down the line—for example try `filtered.length` on your original version and then on this one.

You don't even really need a fold for this operation, though—a `flatMap` will do:

```
trait filterLP extends Poly1 {
  implicit def any[T] = at[T](_ => HNil)
}

object filter extends filterLP {
  implicit def some[T] = at[Some[T]](_.get :: HNil)
}
```

And then:

```
val filtered = test.flatMap(filter)
```

Finally, it's worth noting that this will only work on an `HList` where the `None` and `Some` elements are statically typed as `None` and `Some`—a `Some[A]` for example that's statically typed as an `Option[A]` will get filtered out. This makes it kind of unuseful (at least I can't see a practical use), but there's just not really any way you can perform this kind of type-level filter if you don't know at compile time whether the `Option` is empty or not.

Comment: The flatmap version was actually my first thought i was baffles when i couldnt make it work. Turns out it was because i had types my test variable as HList the rest of my implem was correct. Regarding Option: I am aware but it is not a problem in my case (parboiled2 output)

Comment: The `HNil: HNil` trick is the thing that solved my issue.
But I have no idea why we need to type it this way.