# Shapeless find instance of Some among Nones in an Hlist of Options

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

lets say I have the following class hierarchy:

```
sealed trait Animal

case class Cat(isFriendly: Boolean) extends Animal
case class Dog(color: String) extends Animal
case class Fish(isFreshWater: Boolean) extends Animal
```

Now I have an instance of type

```
Option[Cat] :: Option[Dog] :: Option[Fish] :: HNil
```

But there is a restriction on the instance. It can only be of one of the following forms

```
Some(Cat(???)) :: None :: None :: HNil
```

or

```
None :: Some(Dog(???)) :: None :: HNil
```

or

```
None :: None :: Some(Fish(???)) :: HNil
```

First, excuse any incoherence - it is part of a larger problem that I am trying to solve that is not yet well articulated

Second, the `???` is just my contrived place holder for real instance such as:

```
None :: Some(Dog(brown)) :: None :: HNil
```

Thing is, I am rather ***new*** to shapeless and I don't exactly know if the value of the `???` makes a difference.

---

**Onwards to the question**

*Is there a way to "iterate" over the HList and extract the `Some`?*

I understand that when speaking generically it is not possible as shown in the following two questions. *But* I wonder whether adding the restrictions I set above would make a difference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28598157/101715

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29572541/101715

Comment: You shouldn't use an `HList`, but rather a `Coproduct`, since that is exactly what you want: a list of possible types only one of which has a value.

Comment: Thanks! I had actually thought of that, but for some reason I could not make it work, don't remember why already... perhaps it is the way that I had built the `HLists`... Anyway, is there a way to convert the `HList` to a `Coproduct`? Also, while I try to work it out myself, if you might point me in the right direction it would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: If you want to do it at runtime you could do. `(None :: Some(1) :: HNil).toList.find(_.isDefined)`. But as a co-product would be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the link you gave, such an operation is only possible on `HList` if your values are statically typed as `Some` and `None`, so that the compiler can do anything about it.

If you have additional information that what the type gives (here, the fact that exactly one of the options can be a `Some`), it means that you're using the wrong type, since types are the information you have on values at compile time. In this case, the type you should use is `Coproduct`:

```
type AnimalCoproduct = Cat :+: Dog :+: Fish :+: CNil

val dog = Coproduct[AnimalCoproduct](Dog("brown"))
```

Now, back to your question, assuming you know which are `None` and which are `Some` at compile time.

First, you need to check which `HList` have the property that they are a list of `None`.

```
trait IsNoneList[L <: HList]

object IsNoneList {
  //all values in an HNil are None, since there aren't any
  implicit val hnil: IsNoneList[HNil] = new IsNoneList[HNil] {}

  //if all the values in the tail are None, and the head is None, then all the values are None
  implicit def hcons[T <: HList: IsNoneList]: IsNoneList[None.type :: T] = new IsNoneList[None.type :: T] {}
}
```

So now, if there is an `implicit IsNoneList[L]` in scope, it means that `L` is an `HList` of `None.type`. Let's do the same with the property we're looking for:

```
trait IsOneSomeHList[L <: HList] {
  type OneSome
  def get(l: L): OneSome
}

object IsOneSomeHList {
  type Aux[L <: HList, O] = IsOneSomeHList[L] { type OneSome =  O }

  def apply[L <: HList](implicit L: IsOneSomeHList[L]) = L

  // if the tail is full of None, and the head is a Some, then the property is true
  implicit def someHead[A, T <: HList: IsNoneList]: Aux[Some[A] :: T, A] = new IsOneSomeHList[Some[A] :: T] {
    type OneSome = A
    def get(l: Some[A] :: T) = l.head.get
  }

  //if the head is None, and the tail has the property, then the HCons also has the property, with the same extraction function
  implicit def noneHead[T <: HList](implicit T: IsOneSomeHList[T]): Aux[None.type :: T, T.OneSome] = new IsOneSomeHList[None.type :: T] {
    type OneSome = T.OneSome
    override def get(l: ::[None.type, T]): T.OneSome = T.get(l.tail)
  }
}
```

Notice that if we have an `implicit IsOneSomeHList[L]` in scope, we know that `L` has the property we want, but we can also use this implicit to get the type and the value of the only `Some` in the list.

**EDIT**

Let's give an example:

```
val cat = Some(Cat(isFriendly = true)) :: None :: None :: HNil

IsOneSomeHList[Some[Cat] :: None.type :: None.type :: HNil].get(cat) == Cat(true)
```

Comment: ok... I feel like a complete bumblehead, but I have stared at this for quite some time, I have even tried incorporating it into my code base, but I haven't a clue as to how I should employ it. Also, should the `def`s within `IsOneSomeHList` not have also been set as `implicit`? Could you please elaborate your answer with a usage example? It may be obvious to someone skilled at type level programming but I am evidently not...
Lastly, just to make sure... your code will work _only_ when the HList is explicitly typed with `Some`s and `None`s, right?

Comment: You're completely right, I didn't take the time to fully explain. I put the implicits I had forgotten, and added an example.